# How to json.dumps byte object in python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.x

In python2

```
import json
a = {"text": u"你好".encode("gbk")}
json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False)

>>> Out: '{"text": "\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3"}'
```

I want to get same 'Out' in python3:

```
import codecs
byte_obj = "你好".encode("gbk")
x = byte_obj.decode("utf8", "backslashreplace") # ops, it become '\\xc4\\xe3\\xba\\xc3'
x = codecs.escape_encode(byte_obj)[0] # ops, it become b'\\xc4\\xe3\\xba\\xc3'

# fail, I have to concatenate them

b'{"text": "' + u"你好".encode("gbk") + b'"}'

>>> Out: b'{"text": "\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3"}'
```

In Python3, If there is a way to convert

```
{"text": "你好"}  # first, encoding with gbk, then json.dumps
```

to

```
b'{"text": "\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3"}'  # json serialized result
```

Comment: If I understand what your saying, `repr({"text": "你好"} ).encode('utf-8')` should work.

Comment: The `repr({"text": "你好"} ).encode('gbk')` returns `b"{'text': '\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'}"`,  It can't be json serialize, since repr use single quote mark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you actually want GBK encoding in Python 3:

```
import json
a = {"text": u"你好"}
print(json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False).encode('gbk'))
```

> `b'{"text": "\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3"}'`

Comment: Thanks, can I do that without open(), because I have millions of "text" need to be encoded, each "text" will perform some CPU-bounded operation, I want to save as much as resources as possible.

Comment: @郭泽平 sure, and updated answer, but why encode it if not to serialize it to persistent storage or for transmission?  Unicode strings are (usually) easier to process.  In Python 3, `json.dumps` returns a Unicode string, so you can encode it however you want.

Comment: It should probably be noted that the result of doing this *is not valid JSON*. GBK is a non-Unicode encoding and so won't be understood by most JSON parsers.